# Problem adding entities in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, identity

I have an entity that has a primary key that is set to identity and the type is bigint (long in C#).

When I add a new object to ObjectContext and try to save changes to the database, I get the following error:

```
A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'."
```

I don't really understand what's going on here. True, the identity column is set to 0 by default upon creation, but that shouldn't be preventing EF from figuring out it's an identity field.

What's going on here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently someone created a strange bidirectional relationship between tables that wasn't even supposed to be there.

I deleted it and it's working now.